# Atom, salvar sem BOM

Tags: atom

Estou iniciando com o Atom.
Como faço para salvar ou mudar o arquivo para **SEM BOM**?

Answer (score 1):

aparentemente é um problema a ser resolvido no atom [link para issue](https://github.com/atom/encoding-selector/issues/18)

Comment: Indica um que seja mais estável? Eu usava o PHPStorm, mais a licença de estudante acabou.

Comment: @Tiago Experimente o Sublime Text ou o VS Code

Comment: atualmente migrei para o microsoft visual studio code, feito basicamente da mesma forma que o Atom porém mais estável e com suporte melhor (na minha opinião)